How do I manage to use login and logout functionality using React efficiently
When a user opens the page they must first redirect to login page and after the successful login that person should be able to redirect automatically to "/home" page, but it being tough for me understand the logic that how do I force a user to login
<Router>
  {/* <Navigate to="/login"/> */}
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/test">Test Parent</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/item/">Items</NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/login' element={<TestLogin />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<TestHome />} />
      <Route path="/test/*" element={<TestParent />} />
      {/* below routing way is used to append the /item with /item/:id */}
      <Route path="/item/" element={<TestItems />}>
        <Route path="/item/:id" element={<TestSubList />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>

I tried using <Navigate to="/login"/>
which acted as force redirect to "/login" but I don't know how to get out of if when I successfully logged in and redirect to the "/home"?
Also how do I manage the logout functionality in it?
for now I tried using localStorage for login but still I'm having issue managing it.
